# failed to load openni_kinect libraries

Tags: kinect, openni, turtlebot, openni-kinect, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using my turtlebot for the first time with electric. Every time I try to roslaunch anything that uses packages from the openni_kinect stack (follower.launch, openni.launch, etc), I get a bunch of errors about failing to load libraries from openni_kinect. Here's an example of one of the errors.

```
[ERROR] [1337214239.808330340]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/depth/metric_rect] of type [depth_image_proc/convert_metric]: Failed to load library /opt/ros/electric/stacks/openni_kinect/depth_image_proc/lib/libdepth_image_proc.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_REGISTER_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Cannot load library: /opt/ros/electric/stacks/perception_pcl/pcl/lib/libpcl_visualization.so.1.1: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
[FATAL] [1337214239.809701780]: Service call failed!
[camera/depth/metric_rect-8] process has died [pid 16675, exit code 255].
log files: /home/turtlebot/.ros/log/f32ffc28-9fb2-11e1-ac38-485d603306cf/camera-depth-metric_rect-8*.log
```

There are a bunch of similar errors all with libraries from the same stack. I've tried reinstalling that stack but to no avail. Hopefully this is something really obvious that I'm missing.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34188/failed-to-load-openni_kinect-libraries/) by [selliott](https://answers.ros.org/users/1745/selliott/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like trouble between the version of libmysql that the debian packages were linked against at compile time and the version of libmysql that's installed on your system.

I can see a couple of possible causes here:

- The system is out of date; the ROS packages may depend on some arbitrary library features that it probably shouldn't. Updating should fix that.
- Sourcing multiple versions of ROS in the same shell. I know some of the turtlebot installs source ROS from the system bashrc or /etc/profile, so this could be hiding somewhere non-obvious. This will show up as multiple versions in your $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
- You're pulling in debs for the wrong version of ubuntu; take a look at your sources.list[.d], and make sure the version string in your deb line matches the version of ubuntu you're running

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0